# Why can I not instantiate AccountManager?

Tags: android

I am having trouble instantiating `AccountManager`. When I use:

```
AccountManager s=new AccountManager();
```

I get a compiler error but `AccountManager` is not an abstract class so I don't understand why.

Comment: What is the exact error?  What is the class definition for `AccountManager`?

Answer (score 0):

The `AccountManager` constructor is not for app use so it can't be instantiated directly. Instead you have to use `AccountManager.get(Context)`.

You can take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager).

Comment: How did u knew it does not for app use , and how do I aware of in future ?

Comment: The documentation states how to retrieve an instance of it so you should follow that regardless. However if you look at the source code, the constructors are marked with an @UnsupportedAppUsage annotation.

Comment: Also the constructors don't appear in the documentation at all, which means they're either private or hidden, either way telling you that they shouldn't be used.